# How to print a QTableView

Tags: python, qt, printing, pyside, qtableview

I have a Python and PySide app that connects to a mysql database and displays the results of a query in a QTableView. 
I need to print the contents of the table view.
Here's some code:

```
    self.db_table = QtGui.QTableView(self)
    self.model =  QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
    self.model.setQuery("SELECT * FROM simpsons")
    self.model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self.tr("First Name"))
    self.model.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self.tr("Last Name"))
    self.db_table.setModel(self.model) 

    self.print_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Print")
    self.print_btn.clicked.connect(self.print_btn_clicked)

    def print_btn_clicked(self):
        printDialog = QtGui.QPrintDialog(self.printer, self)
        if printDialog.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
         #printing code
```

I can't find an example for this and I don't understand much from the documentation so I'd appreciate some help

Comment: Start reading Qt docs: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/printing.html

Comment: Thanks, but i have trouble converting c++ code into python. I don't really know c++, but the Qt documentation is helpful sometimes.

Comment: How is this closed as not a real question but the following passes by without a quip? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147030/qtableview-printing?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to dump the table contents into a `QTextDocument`, and then print that.

The following demo uses a simple text-table, but html could be used to get more sophisticated formatting:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        model =  QtGui.QStandardItemModel(rows, columns, self.table)
        for row in range(rows):
            for column in range(columns):
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem('(%d, %d)' % (row, column))
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                model.setItem(row, column, item)
        self.table.setModel(model)
        self.buttonPrint = QtGui.QPushButton('Print', self)
        self.buttonPrint.clicked.connect(self.handlePrint)
        self.buttonPreview = QtGui.QPushButton('Preview', self)
        self.buttonPreview.clicked.connect(self.handlePreview)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonPrint, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonPreview, 1, 1)

    def handlePrint(self):
        dialog = QtGui.QPrintDialog()
        if dialog.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
            self.handlePaintRequest(dialog.printer())

    def handlePreview(self):
        dialog = QtGui.QPrintPreviewDialog()
        dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.handlePaintRequest)
        dialog.exec_()

    def handlePaintRequest(self, printer):
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(document)
        model = self.table.model()
        table = cursor.insertTable(
            model.rowCount(), model.columnCount())
        for row in range(table.rows()):
            for column in range(table.columns()):
                cursor.insertText(model.item(row, column).text())
                cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextCell)
        document.print_(printer)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(25, 2)
    window.resize(300, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks ekhumoro and jdi, both your answers are nice and work, but I can only select one correct answer and I'll give it to ekhumoro, because his method looks nicer when printed.

Answer (score 4):

When searching for an approach to printing a multi-page QTable, you will probably find someone either saying to dump to a QTextDocument as in @ekhumoro's answer, or manually managing the page size on your own, printing directly from the Table.

Here is a rough example of how you could print directly from the table, by doing a custom print method:

```
class Window(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.db_table = TableView(self)         

    def print_table(self):
        dialog = QtGui.QPrintDialog(self)
        if dialog.exec_() == dialog.Accepted:
            self.db_table.print_(dialog.printer())


class TableView(QtGui.QTableView):

    def print_(self, printer):
        model = self.model()

        rows = model.rowCount()
        cols = model.columnCount()

        totalWidth = 0.0
        for i in xrange(cols):
            totalWidth += self.columnWidth(i)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(printer)

        pageSize = printer.pageRect()
        pageHeight = pageSize.height()

        scaleX = pageSize.width() / totalWidth
        painter.scale(scaleX, 1.0)

        totalHeight = 0.0 

        newPage = False
        offsetY = 0
        for row in xrange(rows):

            height = self.rowHeight(row)
            totalHeight += height
            if totalHeight > pageHeight:
                totalHeight = height 
                printer.newPage()
                newPage = True 

            for col in xrange(cols):
                idx = model.index(row, col)
                option = self.viewOptions()
                option.rect = self.visualRect(idx)

                if newPage:
                    offsetY = option.rect.y()
                    newPage = False

                option.rect.moveTop(option.rect.y()-offsetY)
                self.itemDelegate().paint(painter, option, idx)

        painter.end()
```