# Drawing a complex printable table in qt

Tags: qt, qtableview

How  can I draw table like http://jsbin.com/uzOtiw/1? I don't get any idea for this.

Easy to understand example code will be helpful.

Comment: I believe the Qxt library has the ability to create a header like you have in your example. As for printing I do this by generating html. I believe I have answered a similar question here some time ago so I will look for that..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147030/qtableview-printing/4079676#4079676

Comment: Hmm. I may be wrong about Qxt. I can not seem to find that ability in the QxtHeaderView http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/classes.html

Comment: I see people talking about printing, but where in the question was printing mentioned? He just asked "How i can draw table" - drawing it for what purpose is unspecified. Regardless, if you want to print it then I think rich text / HTML is your best bet, or if it's only going to be used in the application itself, then QTableView.

Comment: The current title says "Drawing a complex printable table in qt". To me printable means the user wants the ability to print the table to a printer.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy "Printing" was in the title before the OP edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Sorry, I didn't see that you wanted a *printable* table in Qt. I provided a way to do it in a `QTableWidget` element.

---

This code is uncompiled and not tested but I believe it appropriately reproduces the table that you want:

```
const int ROW = 6;
const int COL = 8; 

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();    
    window->resize(400, 250);

    QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget();

    //Set table row count 1 and column count 3
    table->setRowCount(ROW);
    table->setColumnCount(COL);
    table->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

    // generate the table widgets           (first column)
    QTableWidgetItem* sl = new QTableWidgetItem("SL");       
    QTableWidgetItem* one = new QTableWidgetItem("1");
    QTableWidgetItem* two = new QTableWidgetItem("2");
    QTableWidgetItem* three = new QTableWidgetItem("3");
    QTableWidgetItem* total = new QTableWidgetItem("Total");

    //Add Table items here
    table->setItem(0, 0, sl);    
    table->setSpan(0, 0, 2, 1); // set the sl span
    table->setItem(0, 2, one);
    table->setItem(0, 3, two);
    table->setItem(0, 4, three);
    table->setItem(0, 5, total);

    // generate the table widgets for the second and third columns
    QTableWidgetItem* unit1 = new QTableWidgetItem("Unit1");
    unit1->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    QTableWidgetItem *unit2 = new QTableWidgetItem("Unit2");
    unit2->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    QTableWidgetItem *unit3 = new QTableWidgetItem("Unit2");
    unit3->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    QTableWidgetItem *comments = new QTableWidgetItem("Comments");

    // set the unit things and comments
    table->setItem(0, 1, unit1);
    table->setSpan(0, 1, 1, 2);
    table->setItem(0, 3, unit2)
    table->setSpan(0, 3, 1, 2);
    table->setItem(0, 5, unit3);
    table->setSpan(0, 5, 1, 2);
    table->setItem(0, 7, comments);

    // now set up the product widgets
    QTableWidgetItem *product = new QTableWidgetItem("Product");
    QTableWidgetItem *product2 = new QTableWidgetItem("Product2");

    table->setItem(1, 1, product);
    table->setItem(1, 2, product2);
    table->setItem(1, 3, product);
    table->setItem(1, 4, product2);
    table->setItem(1, 5, product);
    table->setItem(1, 6, product2);
    window->setCentralWidget(table);
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for valued example code. It worked as i wanted to see . Thanks again! However, this time i want to load all the data from mysql database. I wonder if i can apply this same technique to QSqlQueryModel . [Sorry i am new]

Comment: Dunno how i do this !

Comment: help me doing it in QsqlQueryModel? I think i will need to insert the first row but will it not be overwritten automatically? Try to think this code for next level.

Comment: Make a new question for that.

Comment: done ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814568/drawing-a-complex-printable-table-in-qt-and-qsqlquerymodel-qsqltablemodel

Answer (score 0):

Without more context or a more specific explanation of exactly what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to give a really thorough answer, but my initial suggestion might be to try using Qt's rich text support. [This page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html) gives some more information on this. Especially note that `<table>` is supported, so you can draw arbitrary HTML tables using these controls.

Other than that, I'm assuming you have already looked at [QTableView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qtableview.html)?