# Draw, populate and print a table to PDF file with QT

Tags: c++, qt

I successfully created a method that creates a PDF containing some text with QT.
Here is the code:

```
QTextDocument doc;
doc.setHtml("Some Text");

 QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
 printer.setOutputFileName("../out.pdf");
 printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
 doc.print(&printer);
 printer.newPage();
```

Now I'd like to create a table with some variable values inside it.
Something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|                    TableTitle                  |
--------------------------------------------------
|    Column1    |     Column2    |    Column3    |
--------------------------------------------------
|   var1value   |   var2value    |   var3value   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve this? Should I use a library? If so, what libraries do you advise?

Thanks

Comment: You can use an html table to do this. Something like I wrote here to print a QTableView: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4079676/487892

Comment: Here is some good help with html tables: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: This may also help if your data has a fixed layout: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables

Comment: @drescherjm   Thank you! I'm rearranging the code you posted in that Stackoverflow question. I'll read also the other 2 links

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a class that can print any QAbstractItemModel to pdf or postscript with QPrinter. In examples directory you can found exactly what you want.
https://github.com/T0ny0/Qt-Table-Printer

Here is two examples of printing the same table with this class.
[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]